# In Javascript, how can I throw an error if an environmental variable is missing?

Tags: javascript, null, environment-variables

In Javascript, I can access an environment variable like so:

```
pizza = process.env.PIZZA
```

Is there a simple syntax for throwing an error if that envar is missing/`null`/`undefined`? Something akin to Bash `?`:

```
pizza = process.env.PIZZA?  // not real Javascript
```

Yes, obviously I can just explicitly check myself if it's undefined:

```
pizza = process.env.PIZZA; if (!pizza) { throw ... }
```

But this gets repetitive very quickly. Every time I've ever want to access an envar, in any language, I want an error if that envar is missing. Before I write a little utility to do that check (`my_env.require('PIZZA')`), I'd like to be sure I'm not missing a Javascript feature that can easily achieve that.

Is there any simple language feature that can do this? Or perhaps a library that replaces `process.env`?

Comment: Write your own function to do it. Get the environment variable; check for `null` or `undefined`; throw an Error if so; return the value. Then call that instead of going straight to `process.env` for everything.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Accessing a nonexistent property simply returns `undefined`, it doesn't through an error. You only get an error if you try to access the next level, e.g. `process.env.PIZZA.x`

Comment: In the near future, `process.env.PIZZA ?? throw new Error("Missing Pizza")` might work.

Answer (score 7):

Helper function that throws if the environment variable doesn't exist:

```
function getEnv(name) {
    let val = process.env[name];
    if ((val === undefined) || (val === null)) {
        throw ("missing env var for " + name);
    }
    return val;
}
```

Then in code you just say;

```
pizza = getEnv("pizza");
```

Comment: Updated - forgot to add `return val;`

Comment: Yes, a helper function like this is the current plan -- I'm just surprised that I have to write it on every new project (in every language). I don't know who is out there accessing environmental variables that they don't mind being missing (without a default explicltly provided), but it sure ain't me.

Comment: @JonasWilms - what would you recommend throwing?

Comment: A proper `Error` instance maybe